# Is shimano ct-s500 chain tensioner supposed to move around its bolt?

Tags: shimano

I disassembled my Shimano ct-s500 chain tensioner and now I am putting it all together. However after attaching it to the frame it moves  for about 60 degrees around the bolt which attaches it to the frame. Here is a video https://drive.google.com/open?id=1itR1nnxvhlJbIqK0KxWzaiwva47sI4Cj (see the second half of it). Is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, no problem. When there's no chain in place it's normal for rear derailers and this type of chain tensioner to be able to rotate like that.